# Is GNU Radio being used for any Deep Space Missions in development?

Tags: spacecraft, radio-communication, open-source, software-defined-radio

GNU Radio is an open source collection of code and tools to build various radio elements for a "Software Defined Radio" or a radio implemented with the help of an FPGA that is programmed to work as a radio.  The basic tutorial about GNU Radio can be found at the organisation's website [GNU Radio Tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_Introduction).  An introduction to how GNU Radio can be used for satellite communication from Dr. Daniel Estevez is [Here](https://www.gnuradio.org/grcon/grcon19/presentations/gr-satellites_a_collection_of_decoders_for_amateur_satellites/Daniel%20Est%C3%A9vez%20-%20gr-satellites.pdf).

We built groundstation-based GNU Radio receivers and transmitters for some LEO CubeSats for prior missions and are planning to implement a Deep Space Network (DSN) compatible transponder for a proposed mission, and would like to know if anyone has forged this path before us.

I am aware of several software defined radios for deep space like the JPL/Utah State IRIS radio that uses a custom solution, as well as efforts to build CCSDS compatible groundstations that would be able to talk to interplanetary spacecraft, but I've yet to see any evidence of anyone implementing a GNU Radio solution for the spacecraft.  Have we missed some critical capability that makes this approach impractical?

TLDR: Any resources for implementing Deep Space Network (DSN) communications with GNU Radio?

Comment: Could you try to add paragraphing (i.e. adding empty lines) to make this question slightly better structured, and could you elaborate on what the question is, specifically?

Comment: What about the reliability of the FPGA, power consumption, radiation sensitvity, extended temperature ranges? Are these comparable to conventional solutions without FPGA?

Comment: There are a number of Xilinx parts that have a good history of space use that do fine in a moderate to mild radiation environment and typical thermal ranges.  Power consumption is not as great as an optimized ASIC but it's a good tradeoff for quick and easy development.  The JPL IRIS radio is one well known example.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to implement the specification from the [DSN Handbook](https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/dsndocs/810-005/station-data-processing/) in GNU Radio. This has been done on at least one deep space mission recently[.](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/small_spacecraft/capstone)

Comment: Are you referring to the IRIS radio on MARCO?  That's the only SDR I'm aware of recently that may have been in DSN contact, but I wasn't aware that they did their implementation in GNU Radio.